# PHP script downloads the php file itself instead of the file given

Tags: php, file, download

I already asked this question, but not correctly, and I didn't know, that I can't execute a html page and start a download on the same page, but now I know. The main problem actually still remains, I can't get the CSV file to download, it always get the PHP self. The code is executed. I didn't find any information about CSV in the php.ini. I created the file directly before the download (in another page), so it's impossible, that the it doesn't exist.

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['checkbox_put_it_in_CSV_too'])!=1){
  $file=fopen('created_files/Rankrohad_P_2021-04-01.csv','w');
  $filename='created_files/Rankrohad_P_2021-04-01.csv';
  foreach($rankrohad as $line){
    fputcsv($file,$line,"|","'");
  }
  fclose($file);
  $fsize=filesize($filename);
    if(file_exists($filename)){
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header('Content_Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Length: '.$fsize);
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Maybe your browser does not serve php files properly and that's why it's downloaded and not executed? Have you tried echo'ing anything?

Comment: Yes, I wrote a bunch of php files including the page, which created that csv, and it's created, or overwritten well. The php code is correctly executed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your headers. Try this:

```
if(file_exists($filename)){
    $fsize=filesize($filename);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/csv');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Length: '.$fsize);
    readfile($filename);
    exit;
}
```

At Content-Disposition header I escaped the filename and I placed filesize function in IF.

Comment: Thanks! I tried, the output was still the same, but I found a failure in my script! Sorry! I was a dickhead... the Content-Disposition was written with a _ character instead of -. I screwed up. But I found it because of your answer, thank you!

Comment: Be aware that you check the filesize before checking if the file exists and you may consider this a bug in your code, also your script didn't work as it is on my machine because of Content-Disposition header